# Why is it necessary to use edi constraint in this inline assembly?

Tags: gcc, constraints, inline-assembly

**centos 6.5 64bit vps, 500MB ram  gcc 4.8.2**

I have the following function that works only if I use edi as the constraint to hold the string pointer.  If I try to use any other register or constraint`g` or `q` etc, it segfaults.

BUT this problem only occurs when both link time optimization and `o3` are used together.  If `o2` it's fine.  If I don't use `-flto`, it's fine.  But both together then the only register I can use that doesn't crash is `edi`

```
gcc -flto
CFLAGS=-I. -flto -std=gnu11 -msse4.2 -fno-builtin-printf -Wall -Winline -Wstrict-aliasing -g -pg -O3 -lrt -lpthread
```

It seems like there might be some sort of register clobbering going on or something else.  I'm really at a loss to understand why and how to fix this.  Another interesting aspect is the generated assembly puts `rdi` into `rdx` before using the pointer but if I try to use either register as the input constraint... it segfaults!  If it fails under aggressive compiling options it suggests to me either the compiler is stuffing up somehow, or more likely I'm doing something wrong.

```
char *sse4_strCRLF(char *str)
  {
  __m128i M = _mm_set1_epi8(13);
  char *res;
  __asm__ __volatile__(
     "xor %0,%0\n\t"
     "sub $1, %1\n\t"
"1:" "sub $15,%1\n\t"
    ".align 16\n\t"
"2:" "add $16, %1\n\t"
     "pcmpistri  $0x08,(%1),%2\n\t"
     "ja 2b\n\t"
     "jnc 2f\n\t"

     "cmpb $10,1(%1,%%rcx)\n\t"
     "jne 1b\n\t"
     "add %%rcx,%1\n\t"
     "mov %1,%0\n\t"
"2:"
     :"=q"(res)
     :"edi"(str),"x"(M)  //<-- if use anything except edi, it segfaults
     :"rcx"
     );
return (char*) res;
}
```

Disassembled output:

```
00000000000002e0 <sse4_strCRLF>:
2e0:   55                      push   rbp
2e1:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
2e4:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   2e9 <sse4_strCRLF+0x9>
2e9:   66 0f 6f 05 00 00 00 00 movdqa xmm0,[rip+0x0]          # 2f1 <sse4_strCRLF+0x11>
2f1:   48 89 fa                mov    rdx,rdi   //<--- puts rdi into rdx!
2f4:   48 31 c0                xor    rax,rax
2f7:   48 83 ea 01             sub    rdx,0x1
2fb:   48 83 ea 0f             sub    rdx,0xf
2ff:   90                      nop
300:   48 83 c2 10             add    rdx,0x10
304:   66 0f 3a 63 02 08       pcmpistri xmm0,[rdx],0x8
30a:   77 f4                   ja     300 <sse4_strCRLF+0x20>
30c:   73 0d                   jae    31b <sse4_strCRLF+0x3b>
30e:   80 7c 0a 01 0a          cmp    byte[rdx+rcx*1+0x1],0xa
313:   75 e6                   jne    2fb <sse4_strCRLF+0x1b>
315:   48 01 ca                add    rdx,rcx
318:   48 89 d0                mov    rax,rdx
31b:   5d                      pop    rbp
31c:   c3                      ret
```

Comment: I don't think "edi" means what you think it does.  Looking at the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html) (scroll down to x86 family): "e" means "32-bit signed integer constant", "d" means the rdx register, and "i" means "An immediate integer operand".  By specifying all 3, you are allowing the compiler to choose among these 3 options, not (as I suspect you intended) selecting the edi register.

Comment: Another important point: As the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#InputOperands) say, you must NOT modify input parameters.

Comment: I didnt know about the prohibition on modifying input parameters!  I thought that would solve it but alas no.  I changed the code so that %1 is moved into a register and all operations are done on that register but still same problem

Comment: Are you going to post the new code?

Answer (score 1):

@David Wohlferd gave me the answer. It was 2 dumb mistakes I was making due to ignorance and assumptions.  The below code is modified such that the input variable char pointer is not modified by the routine.  It's copied into a register and that register is used.  Also I was mistakenly thinking I could directly specify a particular register as opposed to `a` `b` etc.

gcc still seems to be fussy about what constraints I use.  e.g. If I use `a` and `b` for `res` and `str` respectively, it compiles fine but segfaults on running.  But using `S` and `D` seems to work fine.

@David Wohlferd, I'd like to credit you as the answerer but I don't think I can do that to a comment.

```
char *sse4_strCRLF(char *str)
   {
   __m128i M = _mm_set1_epi8(13);
   char *res;
   __asm__ __volatile__(
     "xor %0,%0\n\t"
     "mov %1,%%rdx\n\t"
     "sub $1,%%rdx\n\t"
"1:" "sub $15,%%rdx\n\t"
     ".align 16\n\t"
"2:" "add $16, %%rdx\n\t"
     "pcmpistri  $0x08,(%%rdx),%2\n\t"
     "ja 2b\n\t"
     "jnc 2f\n\t"

     "cmpb $10,1(%%rdx,%%rcx)\n\t"
     "jne 1b\n\t"
     "add %%rcx,%%rdx\n\t"
     "mov %%rdx,%0\n\t"
"2:"
     :"=S"(res)
     :"D"(str),"x"(M)
     :"rcx","rdx"
     );
  return (char*) res;
}
```

Comment: This could be better written.  And I worry about just assuming rcx will contain str.  And not using the memory clobber even though you are accessing memory.  But if you are happy with it...

Comment: I did read somewhere that pcmpistri returns the result in rcx, so I'm not making an assumption this time. And I don't think I'm modifying memory here so I don't think a memory clobber is a problem.If I'm mistaken, do let me know.  I'm still learning.

Comment: I'm sure there's a more elegant way to write it but it's written for performance.  Like fitting common loops into a cache line etc  If there is a way to make it faster I would love to hear it.

Comment: Doh!  My bad (about rcx).  I don't using pcmpistri and I assumed.  You aren't modifying memory, but you are reading it.  Depending on how str is being created, parts of it could still be in registers.  Faster is always a crapshoot.  Humans are bad at writing efficient asm anymore, so you always have to time it.

Comment: Without having run it, what about something more like (sorry about the formatting): `__asm__ ("xor %[res],%[res]\n\t" "sub $1, %[str]\n" "1:\t" "sub $15,%[str]\n\t" ".align 16\n" "2:\t" "add $16, %[str]\n\t" "pcmpistri $0x08,(%[str]),%[M]\n\t" "ja 2b\n\t" "jnc 2f\n\t" "cmpb $10,1(%[str],%%rcx)\n\t" "jne 1b\n\t" "add %%rcx,%[str]\n\t" "mov %[str],%[res]\n" "2:\t" : [res] "=&r" (res), "=&r"(junk) : [str] "1" (str), [M] "x"(M) : "memory", "cc", "rcx");`

Comment: Why I think this is better: Allow compiler to select registers instead of forcing specifics, use fewer registers, memory clobber.  Oh, and you'll need to add `char *junk;`.

Comment: Tested your code and it compiles to 3 bytes shorter than mine so that's a plus.  Seems to work fine under my stress tests and testing with `__rdtscp` suggests similar or possibly very slightly better performance.  Cheers for that.  It's given me something to study and learn from.